# Combining images in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project to generate a collage in OpenCv for an art project. I first select random frames from a video and then use facial recognition to identify a person in an image, if there is one I extrude the foreground and save the image as just foreground with the background blacked out. I now want to generate these 'stickers' into a larger collage and was wondering about the best way to combine such images and remove the black. Any suggestions or links would be amazing.

Comment: if it is possible I would save it as .png with transparent background (not black) and then use `PIL`/`pillow` to combine images.

Comment: Insert each image into a larger black background image using numpy slicing.